# Unable to print SQL statement in console output

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong here, trying to print the SQL query output in console:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.sql.*;  

public class RetrieveFile {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
try{  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.34.54.100:35120/test1", "user1", "*****");  

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select APPLY from MSG where MID='1234'");  
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
rs.next();//now on 1st row  


con.close();  

System.out.println("success" + rs);  
}catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();  }  
}  
}
```

Actual Response:-
successoracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@66d33a

Expected Response:-
Success NOW(Which SQL query should retrieve)

Comment: rs contains resultset, is you print rs, a hash Address will be printed but not the object data, because rs contains the hash address of the object only, If you wants to show the data, contains in rs, you have to loop and use getString or getInt according to the datatype of column in database

Comment: @Routray Do not include "Thanks" in your questions as it's considered unneeded on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that it seems that your `ResultSet` implementation doesn't override the `public String toString()` method. Because of this the parent's class (`Object`) default implementation is used. And the default implementation prints the class's name, in your example `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl` and the object's hash code `66d33a`.

Instead iterate over the result set and printing each entry line by line:

```
while(rs.next()) {

    for (int column = 1; column <= numberOfColumns; column++) {

        if(column > 1) System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(column));
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I have changed my SQL query from select APPLY from MSG where MID='1234' to select * from MSG_FEES where MID='1234' for which i am able to retrieve most of the column value but some column datatype is mismatching for which i am getting error as "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index", is there a way to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Routray Mostly this indicates, that you try to access an index inside of your result set that doesn't exist, check the value of `numberOfColumns`... But if this issue still exists open a separate question for it please...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate throught he ResultSet object to get the columns returned in your query.

```
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println("success" + (rs.getString(1)); }
```